# Можно ли в JavaScript поставить условие на выполнение .then(Разрешение промиса)?

Tags: javascript

Возникла необходимость поставить условие на `.then`

Если конкретней, то есть ряд промисов. Вот код(`.min` и `.max`, `.required` это промисы. Просто библиотека которой я пользуюсь заменят слово `then`:

```
    const inputSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    [props.id] : Yup[props.dataType]()
    .min(props.minLength, 'Недостаточно символов')
    .max(props.maxLength, 'Много символо')
    .required(props.required)
})
```

Из этого должно получится что то типа(псевдокод с условием if)

```
    const inputSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    [props.id] : Yup[props.dataType]()
    .min(props.minLength, 'Недостаточно символов')
    .max(props.maxLength, 'Много символо')
    if(props.required) {return .required(props.required)} else return ''
})
```

Конкретно вот эта строка

```
        if(props.required) {return .required(props.required)} else return ''
```

т.е. если условие выполнено, то выставляем разрешение промиса

Comment: Это совершенно не похоже на промисы, у промисов не бывает методов min/max/required

Comment: Ну это просто библиотека. Суть одна и та же. Эти min и max просто заменяют слово then, а так это просто набор промисов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно вынести сбор промиса из вызова функции. В этом случае можно использовать обычный `if`

```
var promise = Yup[props.dataType]()
    .min(props.minLength, 'Недостаточно символов')
    .max(props.maxLength, 'Много символо');
if (props.required)
    promise = promise.required(props.required)
```

И дальше передать в вызов функции

```
const inputSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    [props.id] : promise
})
```

Comment: Боже и как я сам не додумался. Очень просто и элегантно. Спасибо!